# Window.Location.Href or other methods of redirecting _self not working (MVC View)

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I'm sure there is probably a very simple explanation for this, but I have tried several methods to no avail.

A little new to MVC but I've set up a controller with a conditional search param and now just need a way of passing it the parameter via querystring.

Direcly navigating to:

```
Collectors/Index?searchName=Tom
```

works perfectly, so I've set up a Textbox on the view to accept the parameter and am trying to redirect user to searchName= Input.

The problem is that for some reason the window.location.href function is not redirecting the page at all.  I've tried window.open method with target set to _self, and that didn't work - however using target _new or not specifying always works.

Is there any reason why the function wouldn't work on the same window?

The following produces an alert before, no redirect and no alert after:

```
        $("#search").click(function () {
        alert("before");
        window.location.href("../Collector/Index?collectorName=Tom");
        alert("after");
```

however this produces both alerts and the redirect (as well as search results)

```
  $("#search").click(function () {
        alert("before");
        window.open("../Collector/Index?collectorName=Tom");
        alert("after");
    });
```

My controller action:

```
public ActionResult Index(string collectorName)
    {

        var db = new CollectorsCRUDController();

        var query = db.GetEXCEL_Collectors();

        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(collectorName))
        {
            query = query.Where(c => c.CollectorName.Contains(collectorName));

        }


        return View(query);

    }
```

Any tips would be awesome!  Thank you!

### Resolved

---

For anyone else that's having a problem with this:

my problem was that I was using the wrong syntax to call the window.location method...

```
window.location = URL
```

not

```
window.location(URL);
```

the full code that worked for me

```
    $("#search").click(function () {
        var query = $("#searchName").val();
        window.location = "/Collector/Index?collectorName=" + query;
    });
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Edited:

`window.location` / `window.location.href` and other variants require setting with the `=` operator, rather than with parentheses (`()`) such as used with `window.open()`.

Change: `window.location.href("../Collector/Index?collectorName=Tom");`

To: `window.location.href="../Collector/Index?collectorName=Tom";`

Comment: Thank you for the quick response, I've tried pretty much every variation of redirecting to _self ... window.location, window.location.href, window.open(.._self), self.location etc.

Comment: try: `document.location.href='/page.htm';` .. clutching at straws though, sorry :(

Comment: Tried that... it didn't work unfortunately. 

I've also just scrapped trying to make it redirect to the right page in case that might be a problem... currently document.location.href("google.com") doesn't do anything either (and i'm still getting alert before)

Comment: btw, I do believe you should be using `=` for `location` / `location.href`, rather than parentheses (`()`). Have you tried: `window.location='page.htm';` ?

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH!!! I never expected this much frustration to boil down to an equal sign instead of a parameter.  You are awesome Alfie

Comment: Haha no problem, pleased I could help :) I will edit the answer to clarify the solution, if you don't mind accepting it?

Comment: No problem, I also added it to the initial post as an edit.  Thanks so much man!!!